# Treemap Ovreall Background Color in R

Tags: r, plot, shiny, treemap

Is it possible to change the overall white background color (not the value color) but the white background color to say black with the treemap package?

```
treemap(agg, #Your data frame object

        index=c("Course", 'variable'),  #A list of your categorical variables
        vSize = "value",  #This is your quantitative variable
        type="value", #Type sets the organization and color scheme of your treemap
        vColor='value',
        palette = "RdYlGn",  #Select your color palette from the RColorBrewer presets or make your own.
        #title="Spending in President Obama's 2017 Budget", #Customize your title
        fontsize.title = 14, #Change the font size of the title
        title = "",
        position.legend = 'bottom', 
        bg.labels = 0, 
)
```

Comment: Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible within treemap, but by converting my treemap into ggplot I was able to control a lot of the formatting. 
[Converting treemap to ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866566/converting-treemap-to-ggplot)