# ggplot2 proportional squares

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I am looking to make some kind of proportional squares (by lack of a better name) visualization in R. Example:

[image: Billion Dollar O-gram]

Any advice on how to do this in R (preferably ggplot2)?

Comment: After learning how to use the tree map package it may be helpful to convert your plot into ggplot2, for ease with formatting. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866566/converting-treemap-to-ggplot

Answer (score 10):

This type of visualization is called a treemap. Appropriately, you can use the `treemap` package. You can find a detailed tutorial for `treemap` [here](https://rpubs.com/brandonkopp/creating-a-treemap-in-r) but I'll show you the basics. Below I show you how to create a treemap in `ggplot2` as well.

## Treemap package

```
library(treemap)

cars <- mtcars
cars$carname <- rownames(cars)

treemap(
  cars,
  index = "carname",
  vSize = "disp",
  vColor = "cyl",
  type = "value",
  format.legend = list(scientific = FALSE, big.mark = " ")
)
```

[image: The output of the treemap function]

## ggplot2

There's also a developmental package on github for creating treemaps using `ggplot2`. [Here's the repo](https://github.com/wilkox/treemapify) for installing the package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library("ggfittext")
library("treemapify")

cars <- mtcars
cars$carname <- rownames(cars)
cars <- mutate(cars, cyl = factor(cyl))

ggplot(cars, aes(area = disp, fill = cyl, label = carname)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(
    fontface = "italic",
    colour = "white",
    place = "centre",
    grow = TRUE
  )
```

[image]